# What is the spinor representation of other groups beside $SO(p, q)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations, spinors

I am studying a lecture about superconformal algebras and it claims that there is a superconformal algebra in $d=5$ where supercharges belongs to spinor representation of $F_4$ (which is an exceptional group) 
as far as I know,  spinor representation is a special representation of $SO(p, q)$. what mean when we are talking about spinor representation of other groups?

Comment: Perhaps it means projective representations?

Comment: @ Seth Whitsitt i am thankful to you if you explain more about it.

Comment: You should cite the paper so I can check to make sure my guess is correct before I write an answer.

Comment: @Seth Whitsitt https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712074  page 31,  sorry it was about G2 group.  my question is not about superconformal algebras and i just want to know about spinor representation of other groups.

Comment: A spinor is a rep of Spin(n) that does not descend to a rep of SO(n). It has no other accepted meaning. One *could* extend this definition for general group $G$ to a rep of $\tilde G$ that does not descend to a rep of $G$, with $\tilde G$ the universal cover of $G$. But $G_2$ is simply connected and centerless, so it contains no spinors in this sense.

Comment: @ AccidentalFourierTransform thanks,  according to your definition yes,  but the article refer to spinor representation of $ G_2 $ group